# 'function' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was following this tutorial https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/univariate-plotting-with-pandas
and trying to do the exercise mentioned with the pokemon database but whenever I try to implement the code below I get the error mentioned below and don't understand what to do. I am using matplotlib.use('agg') because I was getting an error related to Tkinter. I am using pycharm, python 3.6 and I am on ubuntu 18.04

Here is my code:

```
 import pandas as pd    
 import matplotlib    
 matplotlib.use('agg')   
 from matplotlib.pyplot import plot   
 df=pd.read_csv("/home/mv/PycharmProjects/visualization/pokemon.csv")   
 df['type1'].value_counts.plot(kind='bar')
```

error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/mv/PycharmProjects/visualization/univariate plotting.py", 
 line 9, in <module>
 df['type1'].value_counts.plot(kind='bar')
 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error states that `df['type1'].value_counts` is a function.

To plot the result of the function change:

```
df['type1'].value_counts.plot(kind='bar')
```

into

```
df['type1'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```